# Digitized vectors don't match while zooming

Tags: qgis, google-maps, digitizing, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm trying to digitize in QGIS with Google Maps as the background. Digitizing with constant zoom works fine. But if the zoom is changed, the digitized vectors don't match the Google Maps background image.

Comment: Sounds like a common CRS problem from first glance. Make sure on the fly reprojections is ticked.

Comment: Could also be that the different Google Maps imagery zoom levels don't match perfectly. Which location are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

I think you ran into this problem: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6822.

See also [How to Digitize Free Satellite Imagery in QGIS - Alignment issues with Openlayers Plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45449/how-to-digitize-free-satellite-imagery-in-qgis)

Only solution available is to use bing imagery instead of Google, or digitize in Google Earth, export that as kml and use this in QGIS.