# Digitizing with OpenLayers plugin

Tags: openlayers-2

I am facing problem when working with Google Earth imagery. When I am digitizing at 1:1000 it just shifts the shapefiles when I even pan the image. Checked for CRS and everything but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem and provide a link to an image of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into an well known Issue: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6822

Please see this question:[How to Digitize Free Satellite Imagery in QGIS - Alignment issues with Openlayers Plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45449/how-to-digitize-free-satellite-imagery-in-qgis)