# QGIS: How to set coordinate unit using google satellite xyz-Tile?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-maps

I'd be glad if someone can help me with this. 
So, what I want to do is quite basic: Digitalizing shapes with google satellite image using QGIS. For that I am using the Google satellite-xyz-Tile.

Because I want to upload the shapefiles on a google plugin, the projection should be WGS 84 EPSG 4326. If I'm right the coordinate units in this projection is degrees.

When I load the Google Satellite-Tile to my canvas, I have to reset the projection, both on the project and on the Layer - what I do.

Problem: When I zoom to the layer then, the coorinates in the coordinates display and the extent are not shown in degrees anymore, but in meters or feet, although it says in the layer properties the unit would be degrees.

When I now start to digitalize, my shapefiles also have the wrong extent, although I set the same coordinate system (WGS 84 EPSG 4326) and can therefore not uploaded to the google plugin.

Can someone help here?

EDIT: I found that thread from 6 years ago, which is, I think related to my issue: [How to Digitize Free Satellite Imagery in QGIS - Alignment issues with Openlayers Plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45449/how-to-digitize-free-satellite-imagery-in-qgis-alignment-issues-with-openlayer) 
Is it possible that using google satellite-xyz-tile is still a problem in qgis 3.4?

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you're changing the CRS of the layer, and for which layer?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I'm am changing the CRS for the google satellite-layer right after adding the xyz-tile. First I'm changing the CRS in the project properties, then in the layer properties of the google satellite layer: layer properties - source - CRS Selector.

Comment: Aha! That's probably already the mistake I am making. I don't have to change the coordinate system of the google layer, but only of the shapefile by saving it after drawing... Thanks for that hint!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Changing layer CRS in the layer properties is a common mistake. In this case you only need to change the project CRS. QGIS will automatically reproject all your layers "on-the-fly" to display them in the project CRS.